# Child Process Node.js with CasperJs: Cannot find module 'casper'; require statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, casperjs, child-process

I am not sure if I am missing a general understanding of the 'require' but if I try to include casperJs into a node child process I cannot use the module casper.

parent.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    exec('node child.js', {},
        function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    );
};
```

child.js

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    timeout: 180000
});
var meteorUrl = "http://hiddenURL/";

casper.start(meteorUrl, function(response) {
    var _status = response.status;
    if (_status == '200') {
        this.echo("Page: " + meteorUrl + " loaded.");
    } else {
        this.die("Page not loaded! [" + _status + "]", 1);
    }
});

casper.run();
```

Terminal

```
$ casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3

$ casperjs child.js
Page: http://hiddenURL/ loaded.

$ node parent.js
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'
```

Comment: Have you used npm install? Do you have a package.json, and have you added casper as a dependency?

Comment: @DavidKnipe I used npm install; I have a package.json; how do I add casper as a dependency?

Comment: Sorry, I ignored you because it looked like Artjom B had managed to fix it, and seemed to know about casper which I don't. To add a dependency to package.json, just add a line inside the `"dependencies"` object like this: `"casper": "*"`. (Don't forget commas between dependencies - it must be valid JSON.) If you don't yet have `"dependencies"`, add it as a child of the top-level object, i.e. not inside another object. See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS is not a node.js module which is what the error message is actually saying. It is a standalone program that is only installed through NPM for convenience.

Change

```
exec('node child.js', {},
```

to

```
exec('casperjs child.js', {},
```

Comment: It kind of helped to solve the issue but I get:
{ [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?

Comment: What happens if you have `exec('phantomjs --version', {},` in that place?

Comment: Actually I found the issue. I am passing an argument I am not mentioning in the code here. But I am not sure why it throws that error. If I run the file with node child.js it works fine. If I run it with casperjs child.js it throws the error?!

Comment: I really don't know how it would be possible that `node child.js` would work fine.